# Reinstalled Ubuntu and need access to old partion with full drive encryption

Tags: partitioning, encryption, lvm

Ok, so first of I am a completed beginner and I made a big mistake here.

Background
1. I had full drive encryption
2. I forgot my password for logging in
3. I knew there was a way to reset the password, but I wasn't able to do it, so I panicked and just reinstalled Ubuntu using a USB(Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS).

From the Live USB option, I selected 'Something Else' and chose to just keep the drive(that had the full encryption) without formatting it and just changed the file system to EXT4 and mounted it to "/".

Once again, I really don't know what I was doing and was just hoping for a magical fix.

With my newly installed Ubuntu, I ran:

```
lsblk
```

and got:

```
NAME                  MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sr0                    11:0    1 677.3M  0 rom  
sda                     8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk 
├─sda2                  8:2    0     1K  0 part 
├─sda5                  8:5    0   931G  0 part 
│ ├─ubuntu--vg-swap_1 253:1    0  11.9G  0 lvm  
│ └─ubuntu--vg-root   253:0    0 919.1G  0 lvm  /
  └─sda1                  8:1    0   487M  0 part
```

I am guessing the encrypted drive that I had with all my files is in 
**ubuntu--vg-root   253:0    0 919.1G  0 lvm  /**

If I could, I would like to access my files again.

Like I said, I am a beginner and maybe I am not understanding it right.

So, am I correct in my understanding that my old files are still in that drive? If so, how can I access it? I do remember the paraphrase that I use for the encryption.

Comment: Here is one site with some information. I suggest you spend time searching for more information before doing anything more.  It might be too late.  Maybe someone on here knows more to help.  https://www.howtogeek.com/116297/how-to-recover-an-encrypted-home-directory-on-ubuntu/

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know why I couldn't find this document earlier on. Looks like I was using the wrong terms in my search.

Comment: Just be careful, don't try applying information just from one page.  If I was you, would look for as much information before doing anything and would ask again on this or another site if it is correct for your situation.